# VS Code autoformats Python code to use 2 tabs

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

For some reason Visual Studio Code looks like it's foramtting my code to use 2 tabs. I've changed my `settings.json` to use 2 spaces for tabs, which I've verified by pushing the tab button and it uses 2 spaces, as expected. However, 4 spaces (or 2 tabs) are still being used for Python indentation, as you can see in this picture:

[image]

You can see that it's using two (2 spaced) tabs. I've looked at every Stack Overflow post I can find on configuring VS Code Python formatting and nothing I do works. It still autoformats to look like this. This is my `settings.json`:

```
{
  "python.pythonPath": "venv/bin/python3",
  "python.linting.enabled": true,
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.detectIndentation": false
}
```

Does anyone know what's going on? For non Python files it works fine, so I don't know if this is something going on with pylint. This is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured it out - I changed my formatter to autopep8 and told it to use 2 spaces. This is my updated `settings.json` file:

```
{
  "python.pythonPath": "venv/bin/python3",
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--indent-string='  '"
  ],
  "python.formatting.autopep8Args": [
    "--indent-size=2"
  ],
  "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
  "python.formatting.provider": "autopep8"
}
```

I'm a little new to the linting / formatting stuff going on here, but I learned that linting and formatting are different: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_formatting. My linter could be telling me that I needed two spaces, but I needed to configure the formatter to format with 2 spaces when I saved a file.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be achieved by the following steps

> View -> Command Pallete.. -> Preferences: Open user settings -> search python>Formatting:Provider -> select autopep8 -> search python>Formatting:Autopep8 Args > add "--indent-size=2"